# Where is a function call being assigned to in my code? Why is the error presenting itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

My code is causing an error. It says syntaxerror: cannot assign function call. I am using IDLE on windows 10. Here is the code that causes the error:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.Ttk import *
import sys

root = Tk()

class Label:
    def __init__(self, txt, fomtsize, fomtype, hhexx_fg, borderstate, hhexx_bg_truestate, hhexx_bg, yex_pos, why_pos, bordr, masta, hght, wdth, xp, yp):

        if ((hhexx_bg_truestate == False) and (borderstate == False)):
            Label(master=masta, textvariable=str(txt), font=(float(fomtsize), str(fomtype)), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=(int(hght)/2), width=(int(wdth)/2)), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height, width = hght, wdth, x, y = yex_pos, why_pos)
            self.text = txt
            self.size = fomtsize
            self.font = fomtype
            self.color = hhexx_fg
            self.x_position = yex_pos
            self.y_position = why_pos
            self.border = bordr
            self.height = hght
            self.width = wdth

        elif ((hhexx_bg_truestate == True) and (borderstate == False)) :
            Label(bg=hhexx_bg, master=masta, textvariable=str(txt), font=(float(fomtsize), str(fomtype)), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=(int(hght)/2), width=(int(wdth)/2)), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height, width = hght, wdth, x, y = yex_pos, why_pos)
            self.text = txt
            self.size = fomtsize
            self.font = fomtype
            self.color = hhexx_fg
            self.x_position = yex_pos
            self.y_position = why_pos
            self.border = bordr
            self.height = hght
            self.width = wdth

        elif ((hhexx_bg_truestate == False) and (borderstate == True)) :
            Label(bd=bordr, master=masta, textvariable=str(txt), font=(float(fomtsize), str(fomtype)), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=(int(hght)/2), width=(int(wdth)/2)), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height, width = hght, wdth, x, y = yex_pos, why_pos)
            self.text = txt
            self.size = fomtsize
            self.font = fomtype
            self.color = hhexx_fg
            self.x_position = yex_pos
            self.y_position = why_pos
            self.border = bordr
            self.height = hght
            self.width = wdth

        elif ((hhexx_bg_truestate == True) and (borderstate == True)) :
            Label(bg=hhexx_bg, bd=bordr, master=masta, textvariable=str(txt), font=(float(fomtsize), str(fomtype)), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=(int(hght)/2), width=(int(wdth)/2)), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height, width = hght, wdth, x, y = yex_pos, why_pos)
            self.text = txt
            self.size = fomtsize
            self.font = fomtype
            self.color = hhexx_fg
            self.x_position = yex_pos
            self.y_position = why_pos
            self.border = bordr
            self.height = hght
            self.width = wdth
```

(I know that I can improve how I've coded the class, I wasted many lines and I don't use best practices.)

Where is the function call being assigned to anything in this code? Previously I had written in the class:

```
self.label = Label(...)
```

I can understand the error then. I was assigning the label function to something. But this time, I corrected that! Why does the error show up?

Comment: paste the full traceback

Comment: There was no traceback. IDLE didn't run the code, it just said SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call.
See a screenshot of my problem:
https://i.imgur.com/Uh2oHCU_d.webp?maxwidth=1520&fidelity=grand

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Change the name of the class or use `import tkinter as tk` then `tk.Label()`

Comment: I tried that just now. It still doesn't work.

Comment: There is an extra `)` in `width=(int(wdth)/2))`, it should be `width=(int(wdth)/2)` instead.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem!

Comment: Hmmm. I think it should have said unmatched ')'

Comment: Yes, it should have. My IDE is horrendous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to erase the `)` at width.

So the correct string is like this:

```py
Label(master=masta, textvariable=str(txt), font=(float(fomtsize), str(fomtype)), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=(int(hght)/2), width=(int(wdth)/2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height, width = hght, wdth, x, y = yex_pos, why_pos)
```

Also you have to rename your class because `Label` is already used by tkinter.

or

> use import tkinter as tk then tk.Label() - JacksonPro

And at last you have to look at your `.place()` method. I'm not sure what value goes to what argument so you have to correct this.